# CORS error when trying to call MS graph api in angular frontend

Tags: angular, spring

I have a spring boot app authenticating against azure ad.
I retrieve the bearer token back to the frontend after a successfull login.

Now i would try to call the msgraph api using the bearer token in the header but for some reason i get a cors error message when i do it locally.

Does anybody have any idea who i an setup angular to test the feature locally. This is my message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should research how to setup a proxy that points to the msgraph URL when running your app locally. This will stop the CORS issue.

https://www.positronx.io/setting-up-angular-proxy-configuration-via-angular-json/

Comment: Its spring boot serving my frontend. I dont really want to setup another server just for proxying my frontend. Is there really no other way?

Comment: Ah, apologies for that. I'm not familiar with spring boot, but hopefully it should have its own proxy configuration setup. I would try searching for any how-to guides on setting up a basic proxy in spring boot.